# Add additional field to the EncodeJson instance on argonaut-shapeles

Tags: shapeless, argonaut, argonaut-shapeless

Is there a way to specify an additional field which is added to the auto-generated encoder of a case class? The field would be the type field of the sum type the case class is part of, so it generates valid json even in the case the encoder for a subclass is used.